# Scope of system calls using Perl script on apache/unix

Tags: perl, apache, unix

I have an example and question regarding unix/apache session scope. Here is the test script I am using:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -I/gcne/etc 

$pid = $$;
system("mkdir -p /gcne/var/nick/hello.$pid");
chdir "/gcne/var/nick/hello.$pid";

$num = 3;
while($num--){

    system("> blah.$pid.$num");
    #sleep(5);
    system("sleep 5");
}
system("> blahDONE.$pid");
```

I have noticed that if I call this script TWICE from a web browser that it will execute these requests in sequence — a total of 30 seconds. How does Perl/unix deal with parallel execution and using system commands? Is there a possibility that I get cross-session problems when using system calls? Or does apache treat each of these server calls as a new console session process?

In this example, I'm basically trying to test whether or not different PID files would be created in the "wrong" PID folder.

CentOS release 5.3
Apache/2.2.3 Jul 14 2009

Thanks

Comment: I'd either use Perl or use shell commands, but I wouldn't write a Perl script that consisted of only shell commands. To answer your question, Apache is going to start a set number of processes. You will be okay until Apache reuses a process to run this script a second time. You are probably better off using the $PID and a timestamp to do this.

Comment: So why does it take 30 seconds total to execute two of these scripts executed at the same time? It looks like "sleep 5" is global, is "chdir" global too?

Comment: Try profiling your scripts or putting debugging warnings in it to see what is taking so long. Also, you can try running this outside of Apache and see if the same slowness occurs. How long does it take if you only do one request at a time?

Comment: The reason why it is taking so long is obvious - there is a 5 second sleep loop in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the script via the normal CGI interface, then each time you request a web page your script is called. This means each time it gets a new process ID. Basically for CGI's the interface between Apache and your programm are the commandline args, the environment variables and `STDOUT` and `STDERR`. Otherwise everything is a normal command call.

Situation is a little different when you use mechanism like mod_perl, but it seems you don't do this ATM.

Apache does not do any synchronisation, so you can expect up to `MaxClients` (see apache docs) parallel calls of your script.

P.S. The environment variables between a call from apache and from shell are a bit different, but this is not relevant for your question (but you'll probably wonder if e.g. USER or similar variables are missing).

See also for more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html
Especially: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html#behindscenes

A browser may only issue one call at a time (tested with firefox), so when testing it may appear requests are handled one after another. This is not server related, but caused by the web browser.

Comment: Hello, my MaxClients is set to 256, so I should expect 256 parallel processes within apache. My question is why does the "sleep 5" command called via the CGI script block the processing of the other 'parallel' CGI script? It appears as though these two script executions do NOT run parallel, is this to be expected?

Comment: No. A sleep in one CGI call should not affect the second. Are you sure your observation is correct?

Comment: My observation is correct. I open a web browser and call the script once, then a few seconds after I call the same script again. The first webpage loads after 15 seconds, the second a further 15 seconds after. Monitoring the folders/files I can see that this is also the case. The second call only creates the PID folder after the first script has completed.

Comment: Added a paragraph about browsers: Try with two independent instances of browser, computers, whatever - E.g. use `wget` in a two consoles in parallel. I tested with firefox and firefox delays the second call until first is finished.

Comment: Damn, so simple. Sorry my bad. Thanks for pointing that all. Clears up all my questions and confirms my testing - the test script does NOT cross contaminate the folders with incorrect PID files. The system commands ( e.g. chdir ) are process exclusive resources. Thanks